# Is it possible to use countvectorizer with StandardScaler?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nlp

I am using countvectorizer to extract features, and I am wondering if I can scale the features. With the code below I am wondering if I can do some scaling using StandardScaler.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
x_training=vectorizer.fit_transform(df ['var'])
```

Answer (score 1):

as CountVectorizer creates a sparse matrix of features, the StandardScalar function from sklearn will throw an exception as it does'nt take sparse matrix.

Read the [Docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html).